# What is Entity Class?

Tags: spring, collections, annotations, entity

I'm trying to use `MongoTemplate`s `find` method. It wants "entity class" as the second parameter.
I give the model class for this, but it does not accept it. It also doesn't show the `@Entity` annotation. The method is as follows:

```java
mongoTemplate.find(queryBuy , Orders, "orders");
```

`Orders` is my model class and orders is collections name. Here are the annotations at the beginning of my model class

```
@Getter @Setter
@Document(collection = "orders")
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Orders {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MongoTemplate` `find()` methods has as the second argument a `[Class][1]`. You can get a `Class` instance with `Orders.class`. Having said this, please try the following:

```java
mongoTemplate.find(queryBuy, Orders.class, "orders");
```